# Fix Android Studio C/C++ project compile issues

Tags: android, c++, cmake

I have an Android Studio project which has C/C++ functions, when I try to build apk, I get this errors, I have searched online for possible fix but could not ix this particular problem.

Error:

```
C/C++ debug|x86 : CMake Error in C:/Projects/codecanyon-oxoo-android-live-tv-movie-portal-app-with-powerful-admin-panel-v1.3.4/codecanyon-oxoo-android-live-tv-movie-portal-app-with-powerful-admin-panel-v1.3.4/V134/Android/Android Source Code/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86/CMakeFiles/3.10.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:
  cmListFileCache: error can not open file.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I imagine you are running into the path length limit on Windows, use a shorter directory name (or at least don't repeat your very long directory name twice)

Comment: It takes wisdom to have come up with this solution, thanks a billion much this solved my problem @AlanBirtles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows paths are limited to 260 characters by default. The path to `CMakeCCompiler.cmake` is 272 characters long so will cause problems for some Windows APIs and applications. Use a shorter path to fix the problem.